# Is there a way to get the PC register value in CDT Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Currently CDT is integrated to my Eclipse. I am able to see the PC register value too. My current requirement is I need to provide a button to get the PC register value. So if user click on the button PC register value should be displayed in console.

I am goggling n number of threads but could not find appropriate one.

If any one come a crossed this scenario Kindly let me know the way forward.

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

The CDT debugger is a front-end for GDB, so basically if GDB can display it, eclipse also can.
However, I assume it doesn't by your post. this can be a really interesting plugin development assignment for you.
If you're not up for the job, you can ask for this feature in eclipse dev forums

Comment: Thanks for the info. I found different way of getting the PC register value.